# Indentation problem for python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am creating a rest api using [python FastAPI library](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/). In VS code writing the api in python, I am getting indentation error in the editor despite the alignment seems fine. Is this some kind of bug of VS code or am I doing something wrong?
[image: Error]
[image]

Comment: where in the image is the indentation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue on my side. All I did was installed the Pylint extension and seemed to work fine after.